# Can I relay the id of a clicked element into a form in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails app, and I want to capture the id of an element the user clicks, send that to a form that is being shown in the same view, and then save the element id to my table.

**What I'm Trying to Do:** I want the user to be able to leave comments (via a form) next to the text of a blog post.

I will need some way for a comment to know roughly where on the page it was left. Using the Markdown gem, I have added a special Table of Contents option, and every heading in my dynamically generate blog posts receives an id label, like:

```
<div class="container>
       <h1 id="toc_0">The Story Starts Here</h1>
            <p>Here is some example text from the first part.</p>
       <h2 id="toc_1">Here's the second part</h2>
            <p>The story finishes up here.</p>
</div>
```

That's it. Then in my comment has, I want it to include this as an attribute, like here with `area`:

```
<Comment id: 6, username: "StackOverflowUser", post: "Really good post. Feeling good on the Wave.", area: "toc_0", created_at: "2016-07-24 10:10:04", updated_at: "2016-07-24 10:10:04">
```

Is that possible to do that with Rails? Have not seen a related answer. This is not hard at all with Javascript, but I am not sure how I can add it when the new row in the table is created.

#### Additional Information

When I mention this is going to be added to a comment table, here's what the form looks like that a user sees. One solution would be if, after I click on the `<h5>` tag to open a comment, it added that a s line in the form:

**view**

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h5>This is a dynamic title</h5>
        <p>It is generated by Rails in the real code, just showing what would be clicked by the user to open the comment box via the jQuery below</p>
        </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">


    </div><!-- / column -->

    <div class="exampleToggle">
        <%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :post %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5 id="username">Username</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5 id="textarea">Text Area</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :area, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.exampleToggle').hide();
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $("h5").click(function(){
             $('.exampleToggle').show();
             $(this).prepend(whatever);
            });
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [hidden_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field)

```
<%= f.hidden_field :some_attribute, value: 'whatever value' %>
```

Change form to:

```
<%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :post %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h5 id="username">Username</h5>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h5 id="textarea">Text Area</h5>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :area, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :some_attribute, value: 'whatever value' %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks good; however, how I do stipulate that the 'whatever value' part should be updated the the 'toc' value listed above? That's the part I am struggling with. Thank you!

Comment: Are you generating that id or it is autogenerated

Comment: Good question. The id is auto-generated. See the OP for some information on how it works, but short story: it will automatically give each heading a sequential tag (0, 1, 2). This is what I would like to store in the hidden field.